# Grep for lines of text that have one occurrence of exclamation mark

Tags: linux, grep

Let's say I have a file with this content:

```
some:text:!someothertext
another:text:!!anothertext
```

I want to grep only for the lines of text that have only one occurrence of '!'

This is what I have and it seems to work but wonder if there is better way.

```
grep -E ':![^!]' my_tex.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is a *whole line match* that consists of a ! surrounded by zero or more non-! characters - either

```
grep -x '[^!]*![^!]*' my_tex.txt
```

or

```
grep '^[^!]*![^!]*$' my_tex.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want: whole line match that consists of a ! surrounded by zero or more non-! characters. Maybe not surrounded but double '!!'. What is the difference the two solutions?

Comment: @jedi The only difference between the two expressions is that in the first, the whole-line-match is imposed by the `-x` option, while it is done through explicitly anchoring the regular expression with `^` and `$` in the second expression.

Answer (score 4):

The following uses `awk` and its `gsub()` to count the number of exclamation marks on each line.  The command will only output lines that contain precisely one exclamation mark.  The `&` replaces the matched exclamation mark(s) with itself.

```bsh
awk 'gsub("!","&") == 1' file
```

You can do something similar with Perl and its `tr` operator:

```bsh
perl -ne 'print if tr /!/!/ == 1' file
```

With `grep` you can do it as follows, which avoids trying to be smart:

```bsh
grep -F '!' file | grep -v '!.*!'
```

That is, extract the lines that contain a single exclamation mark, and then remove the lines that contain more than one exclamation mark.  It involves a pipeline of two `grep` commands, but it's clear what the pipeline is doing, which could be valuable in many circumstances.  The second `grep` could be simplified to `grep -v -F '!!'` if you want to avoid the specific substring `!!` but still allow things like `!hello!`.

Comment: That's a very awkward, unintuitive and unpractical solution.

Comment: @jedi That's a very imprecise and difficult-to-do-anything-about comment.

Comment: @jedi there are 3 different scripts in the answer, which one(s) do you find to be awkward, unintuitive and unpractical? FWIW I'd use the first one (`awk`) as it's clear, simple, portable to all Unix systems, and easily extended to match different numbers of `!`s.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `sed` :

```
sed 's/!/!/2;t1;/!/p;:1 d' file
```

Or in a multiline portable way :

```
sed '
    s/!/!/2;t1
    /!/p;:1
    d
' file
```

---

Or with line printing disabled can be even more shorter :

```
sed -n 's/!/!/2;t;/!/p' file
```

---

With `GNU sed` and `T` command to check if a sobstitution fails:

```
sed '/!/!d;s/!/!/2;T;d' file
```

---

Those all works the same: trying to replace the second occurrence of `!` in the line. If the substitution succeeded (tested with `t`), then there are at least two `!` in the line and so skip it.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver nice observation! fixed up!

Comment: ... you could golf it down to `sed -n '/!/{s///2;T;p}'` in GNU sed I think

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F '!' 'NF==2' filename
```

output

```
some:text:!someothertext
```